# Why can't the .NET XML parser take special characters in strings?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I'm using the XML parsing methods from `System.Xml.Linq`. I've been ignoring this problem for quite a while now but finally figured I should ask why this is.

If you try putting an open angle bracket `<` inside a string attribute, the parser will throw an exception because it thinks it's opening a new tag. For example:

```
<Foo text="This is my <sample> text" />
```

Why can't it handle this? Anyone who knows anything about parsers knows that this shouldn't be a problem. The parser should understand it's in the middle of an open string, and can treat this character as not special. Instead I have to escape these as `&lt;` everywhere.

The only answer I can think of was that this is a conscious choice. The designers decided that in this situation, it was more likely an error that someone forgot to close a string and not that they wanted this character in the string. Is this hypothesis correct or is there a real technical reason behind this and I'm the one who doesn't understand parsers? And is there anything I can do to not have to escape these characters?

Comment: I'd wager because they wanted to implement the standard, and not some layman's interpretation of it. God knows every other person handling XML doesn't really know what's valid and what happens to be accepted by their crappy parser, no need to make it worse. </rant>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an XML issue - the `<` character is not valid inside an attribute.

You should escape `<`, `&` and `"` in attributes, as defined in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types).

Microsoft has implemented a parser that complies with the specification.

Comment: Well that's a good reason for their parser to be that way. But that begs the question of why the spec designers chose `<` to be invalid in an attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll refrain from asking that question.